# Distribution of number of customers in waiting queue in a M/M/1/S queueing system

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-process, queueing-theory

What we deal with when talking about performance measures of this systems is mostly average values.
But how can I get the distributions of this values, i.e. the distribution of the number of customers in the waiting queue in an M/M/1/S system? Here is how I tried to answer:

The distribution of number of clients in the entire system is:

$P[N = k] = \rho^k P_0$

then, normalizing this equation and sums to S:

$P_0 \sum_{k=0}^S\rho^k = 1 => P_0 = \frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}}$

So, the distribution of the number of clients in the entire system is:

$P[N = k] = \rho^k \frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}}$, with $0 \leq k \leq S$.

Considering that we have clients in the waiting queue only if we have 1 client in service, the probability that we have $k$ clients in queue is equal to the probability that we have $k + 1$ clients in the entire system, so:

$P[N_q = k] = P[N = k + 1] = \rho^{k+1} \frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}}$, with $1 \leq k \leq S - 1$.

For $k=0$ we have:
$P[N_q = 0] = P[N = 0] + P[N = 1] = \frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}} + \rho\frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}} = \frac{1 - \rho}{1-\rho^{S+1}}(1 + \rho)$.

What do you think? Thank you all